# dynamodb upsert from a loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

So basically I have an array(`features`) and want to perform `upsert` operation in `dynamodb` from a `forEach-loop`. the `features` array looks like this: `[{'feature': 'existing_feature', 'visibility': ['should_update']}, {'feature': 'new_feature', 'visibility': ['should_insert']} ]`. Now here update is happening as expected but insert is not happening.

```
update(table, params) {
const query = {
  ...params,
  TableName: this.tableName(table)
}
console.log('update-query', query)
return this._docClient.update(query).promise()


}

updateSupportTierDetails(features) {
console.log('inside updateSupportTierDetails')
const promises = []

features.forEach(element => {
  const params = {
    Key: {
      'feature': element.feature
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'set visibility = :visibility',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':visibility': element.visibility
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
  }
  console.log('updateSupportTierDetails params', params)
  const promise = this.update('features', params)
  console.log('promise', promise)
  promises.push(promise)
});

console.log('promises', promises)

return Promise.all([...promises])
.then(result => {
  console.log('result', result)
  if(result.count === 0) {
    console.log('updateSupportTierDetails: No Upsert Operation')
    return []
  }
  console.log('updateSupportTierDetails: Upsert Operation Success')
  return result
})


}
```

Answer (score 5):

DynamoDb **put** will insert a new record if it doesn't exist or update the existing record if it does (based on the partition key)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property

However if you're looping to upsert multiple items consider a batchwrite instead.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property